# Where is stdarg.h?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, freebsd, libc

On my system (Mac OS 10.6) */usr/include/stdarg.h* is:

```
/* This file is public domain.  */
/* GCC uses its own copy of this header */
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#include_next <stdarg.h>
#elif defined(__MWERKS__)
#include "mw_stdarg.h"
#else
#error "This header only supports __MWERKS__."
#endif
```

So, if GCC uses its own copy of *stdarg.h*, where is it? I have no idea on what
that `#include_next` means (maybe a GCC extension?), nor something about
"MWERKS" (a compiler?).

Comment: MWERKS is probably MetroWerks CodeWarrior - now from [Freescale](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/homepage.jsp?code=CW_HOME)

Comment: MWerks is or was MetroWerks Code Warrior not sure how to find the order of includes

Comment: `gcc -v -E - < /dev/null > /dev/null` prints, among other things, the list of directories that gcc will search for header files.

Comment: @Steve Fallows: Thanks! Hmm, old material. Probably not included in Lion.

Comment: Thanks Zack, I used `\`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1\` -v` to do it, seems to print only what's needed (include paths)

Comment: @Steve Fallows, @Grady Player and @Zack: Thanks for the helpful comments! And @Stephen Canon, @cnicutar and @Anomie: After your `#include_next` clues I found the header. Now it will be a problem to accept an answer.

Comment: wow... I have the exact same problem... Can i ask you how did you resolve it... I am having that issue when i am using Lion. trying to install python-mysqldb. Thanks... Rajesh,.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<stdarg.h>`, even more than most C library headers, tends to be very compiler-specific.  As such, each of the compilers on OS X has it's own `stdarg.h` implementation, found in a compiler-specific location (which is included as part of the default search paths for that compiler).  The compiler finds the generic `stdarg.h`, which basically tells it to "keep looking" (via the extension `#include_next`), and it then finds the compiler-specific implementation.

`__MWERKS__` refers to an old compiler for PPC, "MetroWerks CodeWarrior".

Answer (score 3):

`#include_next` is a gcc extension. As you should know, `#include` has a list of paths it searches for header files. `#include_next` tells the preprocessor to include the specified header checking only paths in the list after the one that contained the current header file.

`__MWERKS__` is a preprocessor macro defined on old versions of [CodeWarrior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeWarrior).