# error when building xcode project, this header only supports __MWER

Tags: objective-c, ios, compiler-errors, header-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is stdarg.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712493/where-is-stdarg-h)

I am getting the following error when building my xcode project:

[image]

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: that post doesn't outline any solution to my issue.. not sure how to proceed

Comment: Where did this file come from?

Comment: I am guessing it was just a part of GCC? It's part of the Kernel.framework

Comment: Well, based on the issue I linked, it seems you are somehow importing a MetroWerks CodeWarrior implementation of stdarg.h when you should be using one that will work for iOS.

Comment: @aherlambang just because the other question has no answer, doesn't mean it's not a duplicate - however, I happen to agree that yours may be a similar question but I don't think it's a duplicate so I'm voting to not close.

Comment: Although I also don't think there's near enough detail here to actually get an answer.